# A while ago and a few minutes ago

Tags: word-usage

If I want to say *"a few minutes ago"*, can I also use *"a while ago"*?

I read that *"a while"* is an indeterminate length of time (usually short).

They say that *"a while"* is :

- some moments,
- some minutes, hours,
- some weeks, months.

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you look "while" up in the dictionary? What did you learn?

Comment: "A few minutes" is also an indeterminate amount of time.

Comment: What if I am a student of a 20-minute phone English class?  My teacher will ask me questions and then I will answer during the first 10 minutes of our class.  On the second 10 minutes she will correct my sentences.  She said, "A while ago you answered, 'I go to work yesterday.'  It should be 'went'.  Past tense."  Is it correct if she will say "a while ago" and not "a short while ago" since the situation is very clear?  We never talked before the 20-minute class.  So if she will say "a while ago" it means within our 20-minute phone class.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

http://dictionary.reference.com/ defines while as:

> a period or interval of time: 
>   *to wait a long while; He arrived a short while ago.*

There is no inherent duration - that must be determined from context. For example:

> The solar system formed a while after the big bang

In which case **while** is about 10 billion years.

> The bus is due in a little while

In which case **while** would probably not be more than 20-30 minutes, could be less is unlikely to be much more - this is implied from the normal schedule for a bus.

Answer (score 0):

"Minute" and "while" both are nouns in the context as above.

*Minute is the known factor
 of time,and to me,a bit prosaic and down-to-earth.

**While, on the other hand, an uncertain period of time, duration of time with an additional sense of softness and mystery.

"Minute" & "While" within the fencing of 'a few____ago' & 'a______ago' mean almost the same time span in the immediate past.

But if I ask someone close to stay longer,I would certainly say,"Stay a while":it has emotional overdose, a sense of attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Context is all important in defining how long "a while" might be (see other answers). Without any further context, in my experience it is most likely the phrase "a while ago" means "not recently".

Example:

> "Have you just bought that big TV?"
>
> "No, I bought it a while ago."

If you want an alternative phrase for "a few minutes ago" you could say "a *short* while ago".

Comment: I would disagree with "normally".  In *certain contexts* it may mean "not recently", but even that leave one wondering what "recently" means.

Comment: +1 - I think you're absolutely right. Unless explicitly qualified as *a **short** while ago*, the most common implication is *some [contextually significant amount of] time before the present*. As opposed to *recent*, which normally means *some [contextually **insignificant** amount of] time before the present*. My upvote is primarily for not falling into the trap of trying to specify any particular clock/calendar duration, since ***context is all***.

Comment: @HotLicks - I agree, context is all important. I've rephrased to change "normally" to "most likely in my experience" to make the answer a bit more factual.